# Are there any institutes removing teachers based on less performance in publications?

Tags: publications, university, job, government-institutes

Consider the four cadres: assistant professor, associate professor, professor and above.

Are there any universities or other institutes across world in academia that removes from office permanently, any person, possessing anyone of the four cadres because of her less or no publishing activity?

I am just asking about existence of organizations with such rules.

Comment: The world is a big place. It is hard to prove a negative.

Comment: Are you looking for a concept like "failure to get tenure" in the US? Though the exact reasons are rarely if ever given publicly, it is well known here that 3-year reviews and tenure decisions at many R1s in the US are focused on research performance, which includes examining quality and quantity of publications produced. The failure to advance rate varies by institution, but some professors do fail to get tenure for reasons that may include insufficient research output. Thus the phrase "publish or perish" - have sufficient research output or you are effectively fired.

Comment: In the US it is hard to remove anyone who has tenure (Associate Professor and above) for any reason other than moral transgressions. Even then it is difficult. People not conforming to the institutions "norms" won't get plum assignments or much of a pay raise, but are very unlikely to be fired. Institutes have their own rules, which seldom include tenure unless associated with a university.

Comment: Why do you call those preople "teachers"? In my opinion, their main obligation is researching, not teaching.

Comment: @user111955 The word "professor" literally means "to teach". Historically universities paid professors to teach and the time and space to do research was considered part of the remuneration package. Even today most institutions (at least in the UK) have 40:40:20 contracts - 40% teaching, 40% research, 20% service/admin.

Comment: @IanSudbery: Yes, this is the historic meaning. However, if you ask 10 professors (at least in my country) how they would call themselfes, they would not say teachers (unless maybe if they explain their job to little children). I'd say that at least 4 would be offended to be called by "teacher" since this usually means high school teachers.

Comment: I've always maintained that a lot of the dissatisfaction that many profs have with their jobs is that they think they are employed for a different reason their employers think they are employed.At your place, the third most powerful person in the university is the pro-vice-chancellor for teaching and learning.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, of course. At least in the United States, assistant professors generally do not have "tenure", and they will be evaluated at the end of the tenure period (typically 6 years). If they do not pass this evaluation, their position is terminated and they lose their job. That happens all the time -- most departments at R1 universities will have a case in the last 20 years where this happened.

Once you have tenure, things become more complicated. There is the concept of a "post-tenure review" at most universities, which is triggered when a tenured professor is not productive for several years (as well as for other reasons, such as misconduct). It does happen that people lose their jobs if they do not pass such reviews, though admittedly this method is rarely applied: In most cases, the person in question just gets poor job evaluations, doesn't get a pay raise, is not further promoted, and gets assigned higher teaching and/or administrative duties than everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, places won't have "rules" as such about papers, but contracts do specify that people must meet "reasonable performance expectations". Universities can and do use this to get rid of even quite senior people (Full professors) who are not publishing/bringing in grants.